How to re-render / refresh a table after the options.data has been updated?
SVELTE 5 + SHADCN: How to re-render / refresh a table after the options.data has been updated? I spent 5+ hours trying to figure out how to refresh a tanstack svelte table. The only way i got it to work was doing this which is ugly:
<script lang="ts">
    import { createSvelteTable, FlexRender } from '$lib/components/ui/data-table/index.js';
    import { getCoreRowModel, type ColumnDef } from '@tanstack/table-core';

    let { data } = $props();

    // Initial data
    let _data = [
        { id: 1, name: 'John', status: 'ACTIVE' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Jane', status: 'INACTIVE' }
    ];

    let options = {
        data: _data,
        columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel()
    };
    
    function setAllInactive() {
        data = data.map((item) => (item.status === 'ACTIVE' ? { ...item, status: 'INACTIVE' } : item));
        options = { ...options, data: _data };
    }
    let table = $state();

    // Use effect() to react to changes in `data`
    $effect(() => {
        if (!data) return;
        table = createSvelteTable({
            data: data,
            columns,
            getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel()
        });
    });
</script>

<button onclick={setAllInactive}>hi</button>
{#if table}
    <table>
    render the table...
    </table>
{/if}

Any help is welcome!
I tried everything to no avail

Try useMemo & useState instead of useEffect: https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/faq#:~:text=TanStack%20Table%20is%20designed%20to,infinite%20loop%20of%20re%2Drenders.

Ok I figured it out. The issue was that under svelte's new reactivity model, the options.data was not being updated when the reference changed. The docs states that the table is reprocessed when the reference to data is updated. Using a rune for data and reassigning the data rune was not enough to force a reprocess. Instead what needs to be done is make options.data a getter function. Beyond my pay grade / IQ to understand what the hell is going on other than appreciate that it now works:
let { data }: { data: PageData } = $props();

let options = {
    get data() {
        return data.data;
    },
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel()
};
let table = createSvelteTable(options);

async function setAllInactive() {
    await invalidate('tan:load');
}

